# Remove Duplicate based on 2 columns in Google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code removes the duplicate in the column name called "Receipt Number"

How to modify this code if the conditions matches to two column as duplicate. (i.e. Receipt Number Column and Mobile Number Column should be duplicate at the same time)

```
  function removeDuplicates() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Records");
  var vA=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var hA=vA[0];
  var hObj={};
  hA.forEach(function(e,i){hObj[e]=i;});//header title to index
  var uA=[];
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(uA.indexOf(vA[i][hObj['Receipt Number']])==-1) {
      uA.push(vA[i][hObj['Receipt Number']]);
    }else{
      sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++);
    }  
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share a sample sheet to check how the data is arranged? Always try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to remove the duplicated rows by using the condition of 2 columns.
- For example, when the columns of `Receipt Number` and `Mobile Number` are as follows, you want to delete the following 2 rows (4 and 5).

  ```
    1  Receipt Number  Mobile Number
    2  a2              b2
    3  a3              b3
    4  a2              b2 <--- delete
    5  a3              b3 <--- delete
    6  a2              b3
    7  a3              b2
  ```

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification? In this modification, `removeDuplicates` is used.

#### Modified script:

```js
function removeDuplicates() {
  var checkHeadeTitles = ["Receipt Number", "Mobile Number"]; // This header titles are from your question.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Records");
  var header = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var columnNumber = checkHeadeTitles.map(e => {
    var idx = header.indexOf(e);
    if (idx == -1) {
      throw new Error(`No header tilte of '${e}'.`);
    }
    return idx + 1;
  });
  sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).removeDuplicates(columnNumber);

  var row = sh.getDataRange().getValues().findIndex(r => r.join("") == "");
  if (row == -1) return;
  sh.deleteRow(row + 1);
}
```

- When this script is run to the above sample sheet, rows 4 and 5 are deleted.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [removeDuplicates(columnsToCompare)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removeduplicatescolumnstocompare)

Comment: This works, but when the form enters a new data entry it's getting one row empty and registers the new data in next row. Check this screenshot https://i.imgur.com/GLqa8YP.jpg

Comment: @Miyer Thank you for replying. About `This works, but when the form enters a new data entry it's getting one row empty and registers the new data in next row. Check this screenshot i.imgur.com/GLqa8YP.jpg `, what is `when the form enters`? Can I ask you about the detail of it? Because, in your question, I cannot find about it. By this, I cannot understand `when the form enters`. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: I've set the trigger in google sheets' app script to remove duplicates if the mobile number and the receipt number is the same on form submit. After deleting the duplicate, the next non duplicate entry is skipping a row and registering it on other row.

Comment: Please refer to this sheet 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ouwy1P7aoki9fwycaJMWV3yMfgaLYTNJQ9yf9cUycwc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Miyer Thank you for replying. From your reply, I updated my proposed script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Miyer About `I've set the trigger in google sheets' app script to remove duplicates if the mobile number and the receipt number is the same on form submit. After deleting the duplicate, the next non duplicate entry is skipping a row and registering it on other row.`, in this case, when you run this script?

Comment: I've set the trigger to run the script on form submission.

Comment: @Miyer Thank you for replying. In my updated script, after the duplicated rows were removed, the empty row is removed. From `I've set the trigger to run the script on form submission.`, in this case, if the submitted row is not the last row and empty rows are created, the empty rows are removed by the updated script. How about this?

Comment: @Miyer Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Records");
  var [hA, ...vA] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var idx = {};
  hA.forEach(function (e, i) { idx[e] = i; });
  var uA = [];
  var d = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < vA.length; i++) {
    let x = `${vA[i][idx['Receipt Number']]}-${vA[i][idx['Receipt Number']]}`
    if (!~uA.indexOf(x)) {
      uA.push(x);
    } else {
      sh.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++);
    }
  }
}
```